# Running a timertask is not working because of unusual syntax error

Tags: java

Newbie question:I have been trying to run a timer. But I get an unusual error. Here is the code below.

```
class Helper extends TimerTask 
{ 

    public static int i = 0; 

    public void run() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Timer ran " + ++i); 
    } 
} 



public class Test 
{ 
    Timer timer = new Timer(); 
    TimerTask task = new Helper(); 
    timer.schedule(task, 2000, 5000); 
}
```

The error I m getting is on 
timer.schedule(task, 2000, 5000);

The error is called syntax error ")" delete this token

I have checked and the code would not run. without it aswell

Comment: Is the actual code `timer.schedule()task, 2000, 5000)` or `timer.schedule(task, 2000, 5000)` ?

Comment: Its timer.schedule(task, 2000, 5000);

Comment: can you also write your imports, may be you have imported different timer

Comment: import java.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Timer;

Answer (score 3):

This is a statement:

```
        timer.schedule(task, 2000, 5000);
```

A statement needs to go inside a method. Add a `main` method to your class and put your declarations and your statement there.

Comment: Just another example of how javac's error messages can be so confusing that the error lies completely elsewhere.

Comment: it's already in the main "class public class hello {

  public static void main(String[] args) { code is in here } }"

Comment: @propertywebsite I answered the question as asked, there was no main method there. If you have a different question (after having updated your code, for example), feel free to ask a new question.